# Please help me redirect old url to new url using htaccess

Tags: apache

I have some old urls from our old site as follows:

http://www.example.com/archives/2006/08/test.html

I want all my urls as shown above, starting with www.example.com/archives/* to point to www.example.com/gossip

Can anyone please give me the right htaccess code to do the same? Thanks a lot!

Kip

Answer (score 0):

This will do what I think you're asking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/archives/.*$ /gossip [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi this didn't work at all. Won't you need a rewritecond statement as well? Thanks

Comment: No, condition is not required. It works for me. You need to hit something like `/archives/123` for it to work as you stated `/archives/*`

Comment: How about if it's /archives/2013/test.html ? would it work still?

Comment: Absolutely. It sounds like you may not have the rewrite module enabled if this is not working. You could also try setting `RewriteBase /`

Comment: The rewrite module is enabled and working fine. The code you gave didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Also, the rewriteengine on statement is already in place in my .htaccess file do I need to rewrite that line?